# SQL Server 2012 query in an ASP.NET MVC C# function

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project and this is my first project in ASP.NET. I a have function that should retrieve data from my SQL Server database.

My function looks like this:

```
public List<Employees> GetEmployees(int? ID)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Employees T where T.Account_ID in (select A.Account_ID from Accounts A where Empl_ID = @UID)", con);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UID", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters["@UID"].Value = ID;

    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
```

With this code above and when it reach the "if" statement, `dr.HasRows` is equal to null and it stops. While if I replace the "@UID" with one of Empl_ID like code below, it works perfectly.

```
public List<Employees> GetEmployees()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Employees T where T.Account_ID in (select A.Account_ID from Accounts A where Empl_ID = 1)", con);

    con.Open();

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
```

Any ideas or suggestions, please...

Thanks in advance

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@UID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID` is enough... where you're calling `GetEmployees` method?

Comment: `dr.HasRows` is not nullable, so unless you meant "false" instead of "null" something is fishy

Comment: Also I am assuming your `ID` parameter is indeed set to `1`?